# how to put an icon on top of jsTree tree

Tags: html, css, jstree

so i have a [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/) tree, and i wish i could put a 'lone star' type icon like this...

at the very top of the tree:

[image: loneStar]

jsTree is jquery plugin, that provides interactive trees. It is absolutely free, open source and distributed under the MIT license. jsTree is easily extendable, themable and configurable, it supports HTML & JSON data sources and AJAX loading.

jsTree functions properly in either box-model (content-box or border-box), can be loaded as an AMD module, and has a built in mobile theme for responsive design, that can easily be customized. It uses jQuery's event system, so binding callbacks on various events in the tree is familiar and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a div above the container, like so:

```html
<div>
  <img src="star.png">
</div>
<div id="container" role="main" style="height: 430px;">
  <div id="tree" class="jstree jstree-1 jstree-default jstree-default-small" role="tree" aria-multiselectable="true" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="/" aria-busy="false" style="height: 430px;">
    <ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children jstree-striped" role="group">
      <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="1" aria-labelledby="/_anchor" aria-disabled="true" aria-expanded="true" id="/" class="jstree-node  jstree-open jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor  jstree-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="/_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon folder jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>root</a>
        <ul role="group"
        class="jstree-children">
          <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="MENU1_anchor" aria-expanded="false" id="MENU1" class="jstree-node  jstree-closed"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="MENU1_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon folder jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>MENU1</a>
          </li>
          <li role="treeitem" aria-selected="false" aria-level="2" aria-labelledby="MENU2_anchor" aria-expanded="false" id="MENU2" class="jstree-node  jstree-closed jstree-last"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl" role="presentation"></i><a class="jstree-anchor" href="#" tabindex="-1" id="MENU2_anchor"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon folder jstree-themeicon-custom" role="presentation"></i>MENU2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="data" style="height: 430px;">
    <div class="content code" style="display: none; height: 430px;">
      <textarea id="code" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="content folder" style="display: none; height: 430px;"></div>
    <div class="content image" style="display: none; position: relative; height: 430px;">
      <img src="" alt="" style="display:block; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; padding:0; max-height:90%; max-width:90%;">
    </div>
    <div class="content default" style="text-align: center; height: 430px; line-height: 430px;">Select a file from the tree.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not have a star.png, but it looks like this

[image]